# Jquery | How to duplicate input content?

Tags: jquery

What I need is to duplicate the input 5 times,

And paste it on the textarea

How to do it please?

http://jsfiddle.net/ydr52kbx/30/

```
<div id="main">1234</div>
<text id="test"></textarea>

var copypass = $('#main').html();
for (var i = 1;i < 5;i++){
$('#test').append(copypass.clone());
}
```

Comment: When do you need to duplicate the input? On every keystroke? When a button is pressed? Something must trigger the duplication event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String#repeat` and set the value to the textarea:

```js
var copypass = $('#main').html();
$("#test").val(copypass.repeat(5));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">1234</div>
<textarea id="test"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you, shorter and better!:)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to take clone if you are taking html. Also `<text>` should be changed to `<textarea>` Check this.

```
var copypass = $('#main').html();
for (var i = 1;i < 5;i++){
  $('#test').append(copypass);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

first change `<text` to `<textarea`

```js
var copypass = $('#main').html();
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  $('#test').append(copypass); //remove clone
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">1234</div>
<textarea id="test"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you, i will check it!